# Wordpress: change upload dir conditionally

Tags: php, wordpress

for a theme i'm creating I need a possibility to upload images through the theme-settings page. No problem so far. But the images that uploaded through that specific settings page should be stored in a different dir then the standerd upload dir, or at least have something to make them different from 'other' media.

I did find a nice script to change the upload dir:

```
function ml_media_upload_dir($upload) {
global $user_ID;
if ((int)$user_ID > 0) {
    $upload['subdir'] = "/" . $user_ID.'test'.$ID;
    $upload['path'] .= $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url'] .= $upload['subdir'];
}

return $upload; } add_filter('upload_dir', 'ml_media_upload_dir');
```

By now, the upload dir is changed to a specific user_ID. But I would change the dir only when the media uploader is fired from the specific theme-options page. See screenshot below.

Would be great to get some comments on how to handle this; after searching for hours and hours still haven't found a solution.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one solution could be to [(temporarily) overwrite the core function with a filter](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-overwrite-wordpress-core-functions). You could add the filter before the upload is initiated on your custom page, and possibly remove the filter again once it's done.

Not tested. Good luck!

Comment: that's one of the solutions I tried. But the filter should be added in functions.php to work, as far as I figured out. So when I use it in options-interface.php , the page where the theme-options-framework initializes the uploader, it simply doesn't work. As is stated here [http://cl.ly/EuuO]

Comment: Just used a less nice workaround; think it would be pretty hard to use the right hook. Thanks anyway